# How to get the desired processing value of response of sampler in Jmeter?

Tags: json, performance, jmeter, load, jmeter-5.0

I am having Post request sampler for refreshing the record in database. The response json of the sampler is as
{
submitter:"tester",
status: Get start
}
Before executing the next sampler I have to wait and verify if the status of the response json is changed to
{
submitter:"tester",
status: Completed
}

Can you please help me with example on how can i perform this conditional scenario. I cannot retrigger the sampler because re triggering sampler will start process again

Answer (score 0):

The response doesn't get "changed", most probably your browser (or other API client) periodically sends the requests which query the status of the operation.

You can do the same by:

1. Putting the exact replica of this status request under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter)
2. Use the following [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) function as the condition:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${status}" != "Completed",)}
   ```
3. Add [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the status request and configure it like:

   [image]

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution but when I am running in while loop it is executing sampler again and again. I have the condition where I have to hit sampler once and get response status as Completed